# Links in nextjs not functioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

For some reason my links in next.js dont seem to work. I am using a custom _document.js and _app.js file.

Here is the header file:

```
          <header>
                <div className="header__wrapper">
                    <Link href="/">
                        <a className="header__title">...</a>
                    </Link>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <Link href="/projects">
                                    <a>Projects</a>
                                </Link>
                                <Link href="/mission">
                                    <a>Mission</a>
                                </Link>
                                <Link href="/Affiliate">
                                    <a>Affiliate</a>
                                </Link>
                                <Link href="/careers">
                                    <a>Careers</a>
                                </Link>
                                <Link href="/contact">
                                    <a>Contact</a>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
```

Comment: Can you check the chrome devtools console to see if there is an error in there when you click each link?

Comment: there's no issue

Comment: One thing I've just noticed is you shouldn't need <a> tags inside your links, Links should render <a> tags anyway.